# Trying to transfer data between columns in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with a table 'testimport'.
The table contains 
- a column (DateOccurred) which is in datetime format and contains 0000-00-00 00:00:00
- a column (Comments) which contains 20/03/2013 14:17 in varchar(255) utf8_general_ci format.

I am trying to transfer the content of 'Comments' to 'Dateoccurred' where it should be stored as a date/time, but only for rows with the ID of 2.

I tried this (and various variations) with no luck.

```
UPDATE testimport SET DateOccurred = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Comments, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') WHERE ID=2
```

This results in the 'DateOccurred' column being changed to a content of 'Null'.

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Hmm, try in the STR_TO_DATE without `:%s`? Aaah, as answered, iPhone is a bitch :D

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
STR_TO_DATE(Comments, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s')
```

to

```
STR_TO_DATE(Comments, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```

as you don't have a seconds marked. Also, minutes use `%i` and hours need `%H`.

Check complete list here: [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

---

Your complete query can be shortened/modified to

```
UPDATE testimport 
SET DateOccurred = STR_TO_DATE(Comments, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
WHERE ID = 2
```